# Does Refactoring of expressions into a function have a performance impact?

Tags: java, refactoring

given following simple example code

```
rawData.matches(".*[a-zA-Z\\-].*")
```

I have two possibilities of refactoring:

1) refactoring into a variable

2) refactoring into a function

Is there any performance impact on (2)?

AFAIK the JVM inlines all function calls and it should have no impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this call multiple times then the best thing would probably be to get rid of the magic `String` literal in the argument.

Other than that the performance improvements are probably miniscule and unimportant and it's all down to preference on whether or not you want to wrap it in another function.

Also try not to look into premature optimization too much.

Comment: I have really ugly legacy code (_godclass_ , methods of several hundreds line length), and I'm trying my best to make any sense of it. And refactoring of such statements in the one or the other form helps to increase readability and my understanding of what the code does. So my primary interest is, making this beast readable. And my concern was, if that has any impact whatsoever.

Comment: actually String literals are automatically interned. So, even if he uses the same call in several places, the performance impact will be the same. Though it would definately improve readability

Comment: But that leads to another refactoring :] instead of refactoring into a boolean, I could refactor it to a variable `String badInput=".*[a-zA-Z\\-].*"` which leads to `rawData.matches(badInput)`

Comment: Refactoring a class that you might not fully understand might be risky by itself. You constantly have to watch out for landmines. For instance you might want to refactor the `".*[a-zA-Z\\-].*"` into an optimal String variable let's say `static final String badInput=".*[a-zA-Z\\-].*"` which looks nice and clean at first, but then some other thing might want to modify the `String` for whatever reason (adjusting the regex etc) and since I put it as `final` the adjusting would fail and the application would break.